# What are the standard solutions to enable new users to interact with a DApp contract for free without gas fees?

Tags: solidity, web3js, remix, tokens, ethereum-wallet-dapp

I'm developing a decentralized application (Dapp) where new users receive a free NFT upon registration. I want to allow these users to list their NFTs for sale without requiring them to have any cryptocurrency in their wallets to cover gas fees for smart contract interactions.

I've considered the option of sending new users a small amount of cryptocurrency, but I'm also interested in exploring other solutions. I've heard about meta transactions as a potential way to achieve this, but I'm not sure if it's a widely accepted standard in the industry.

Are there established best practices or standard solutions for enabling new users to interact with smart contracts for free or with minimal gas fees when they initially have empty wallets? Any insights or guidance on how to implement such a feature in my Dapp would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, meta-transactions are the way. They are widely used in the industry.
You can either build your own meta transaction structure, but that would need much time and advanced knowledge of solidity, on the other hand you can check out [Thirdweb](https://youtu.be/4czUCGqa4IM?si=TD_ChwvUU8VenIU9),[biconomy](https://docs-gasless.biconomy.io/products/enable-gasless-transactions), etc.

Answer (score 0):

I see two ways for you:

1. The use of meta-transaction, which is more standard and requires the desired infrastructure to connect with your blockchain and dapp, such as having a wallet installed and connected to the desired network, etc.
2. Creating a connection through the backend and using a private key to perform all transactions, in this way everything happens in the backend and the user even no need a wallet. In this method, in fact, much attention should be paid to security, because when the private key is exposed, the entire Depp will fall into the hands of the hacker, and you need more knowledge.